# Isotope Masonry items are overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using Isotope masonry library, Each items has different height according to their content

So I'm using this code for displaying them :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var $container = $('.members_results').imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
              itemSelector : '.block-member', 
              layoutMode : 'masonry',
              percentPosition: true
        });
    });
});
```

But I have this displayed :

[image]

They are overlapping themselves, and I don't know how to fix it..

By the way I set `height: auto;` for `.block-member`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No I get 0 errors in the console

Comment: Ok thank you. I assume you've tried the suggestion in my answer? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the $container variable to the result of a function, within which the variable is used. I believe you should assign it first, something like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var $container = $('.members_results');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector : '.block-member', 
            layoutMode : 'masonry',
            percentPosition: true
        });
    });
});
```